# TCP over TCP with SOCKS vs VPN approach

Tags: tcp, vpn, socks

When using a VPN (such as OpenVPN) to make my traffic transit through a specific machine I get TCP over TCP issues and my download speed collapses.

I don't have that problem when I use a SOCKSifier (such as Redsocks) and SOCKS server (such as Dante).

As far as I can understand, both programs create an additional TCP connection to transfer the data. So why is the behavior different?

I've done a lot of reading on TCP over TCP issues, and from my understanding connections collapse because of retransmits happening on both the original TCP connection and the tunnel's connection. Do SOCKSifiers handle these differently than VPNs?

Comment: Are you sure that your VPN uses TCP? Lots of VPN use or can use UDP, including OpenVPN.